# Unable to decode a csv file that is downloaded using python script from sharepoint

Tags: python-3.x, csv, sharepoint, unicode, office365

I am unable to decode a csv file that i downloaded using api from sharepoint, I tried to use UTF-8, UTF-16 for decoding I also try a lot of encoding style for this.

```
with open(file_path, 'wb') as local_file:
    file  = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_url(sharepoint_csv)
    file.download(local_file)
    ctx.execute_query()`
    

with open('book.csv', 'rb') as file:
    binary_data = file.read()


csv_content = binary_data.decode('utf-8')

print(csv_content)
```

so this is my code where I download the csv file from sharepoint then decoding that file which is the book.csv file.

The error is: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 22: invalid start byte`

Comment: Do you have access to the sharepoint folder? Can you upload a file you know is utf-8, then download it with your code and see if it's properly decoded?

Comment: 1) Why are not using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to read the file? 2) Have you tried opening the file in text mode?

Comment: @ZachYoung Yes I have an access to the sharepoint folder, that is why I am able to download the csv using office365 python module. I tried different types of encoding styles but it doesnt decoded to what I am expecting to.

Comment: @AdrianKlaverI have tried opening it using csv module in text mode, but since it is encoded in unicode it is having an error.

Comment: So you’ve uploaded your own utf-8 file and downloaded it with your code?

Comment: Thank you! @ZachYoung I got what you mean, so the csv file that I am downloading is save as a excel workbook, and I tried creating a csv file that is save in CSV UTF-8 comma delimeted, then I can get the content of the csv file now. Thanks again zachYoung